# Android Studio Project - Firebase and Graph

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, graph

I can't transfer the data of the database and make it as input for the bar graph. Can anyone know this?

[here's the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxOhJ.jpg)

I don't know the problem is it just won't work. Take note that there's no error while the application is running so really don't know how to fix it. Please help me.

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.greenerthumb.databinding.ActivityTrackingHistoryBinding;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.XAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.YAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarEntry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.IndexAxisValueFormatter;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ColorTemplate;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

public class TrackingHistory extends AppCompatActivity {
    ActivityTrackingHistoryBinding binding;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    private TextView greetingsTxt;

    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;


    private List<String> monthValues = Arrays.asList("January","February","March","April", "May", "June", "July", "August","September","October","November","December");

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityTrackingHistoryBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tracking_history);

        greetingsTxt = findViewById(R.id.greetings);
        showGreetings();


        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Monthly History").child("January");
        float rawData = monthJanuary;
        getJanData();




        BarChart barChart = findViewById(R.id.historyMonth);
        barChart.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(false);

        ArrayList<BarEntry> entries1 = new ArrayList<>();
        entries1.add(new BarEntry(0, rawData));



        YAxis yAxis = barChart.getAxisLeft();
        yAxis.setAxisMaximum(0f);
        yAxis.setAxisMaximum(500f);
        yAxis.setAxisLineWidth(2f);
        yAxis.setAxisLineColor(Color.BLACK);
        yAxis.setLabelCount(10);

        BarDataSet dataSet = new BarDataSet(entries1, "MONTH");
        dataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.MATERIAL_COLORS);

        BarData barData = new BarData(dataSet);
        barChart.setData(barData);

        barChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
        barChart.invalidate();

        barChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(monthValues));
        barChart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        barChart.getXAxis().setGranularity(1f);
        barChart.getXAxis().setGranularityEnabled(true);
        barChart.animateY(5000);
        barChart.animateX(5000);


       
        

    private void getJanData() {
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Float value = snapshot.getValue(Float.class);
                monthJanuary = value;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(TrackingHistory.this,"Failed to get data.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

I already tried several methods, but the graph is still empty.

Comment: You data is empty as obviosuly `FirebaseDatabase` works asynchrounous ... your `getJanData` doesn't does what it promise... it just starts process of getting data ... and data are ready to use in `onDataChange` not right after `getJanData` ends ... even if ... you do nothing with `monthJanuary` after this call so ... your code is FUBAR

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: As Selvin commented: data is loaded from Firebase (and most modern cloud APIs) asynchronously. In your case, your code that builds the chart runs before the `onDataChange` ever executes. I recommend setting breakpoints and running in the debugger, or adding some logging to verify this - as it's a very common source of confusion. --- To solve the problem, any code that needs data from the database will have to be inside `onDataChange`, be called from there, or be otherwise synchronized.